# SQL percent calculation with group in the original table

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a problem using SQL :

I have a table :

```
School Name  |  Class |   Studends  
===================================  
Golden       |  1     |   20  
Red          |  1     |   80  
Golden       |  2     |   7  
Red          |  2     |   14  
Golden       |  3     |   3  
Red          |  3     |   1
```

And I want to have the following results :

```
School Name  |  Class |   Percent     
======================================  
Golden       |  1     |   20 %  
Red          |  1     |   80 %  
Golden       |  2     |   33 %  
Red          |  2     |   66 %  
Golden       |  3     |   75 %  
Red          |  3     |   25 %
```

I try to find the solution but didn't find, anyone have the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If your RDBMS supports windowed aggregates

```
SELECT 
    School_Name,
    Class,
    100.0 * Studends / SUM(Studends) OVER (PARTITION BY Class ) AS Percent
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a."School Name",
    a.Class,
    a.Studends / SUM(b.Students)
FROM YourTable a 
LEFT JOIN YourTable b ON a.Class = b.Class 
GROUP BY 
    a."School Name",
    a.Class,
    a.Studends,
    b.Class
```